# AppSee Free or not?

Tags: google-fabric, appsee

Fabric.io seems to say on the front page that everything is free.  Yet when i try to set up AppSee, the Fabric MAC desktop client says it will set up an AppSee account for me (or at least that is what i remember).  But part of the AppSee install process through Fabric.io desktop client is to ..

> We'll need your existing API key found in the Appsee dashboard to
>   complete the installation of this kit.

Yet when i try my Fabric.io credentials on AppSee to get to my dashboard, AppSee doesn't know me.  I went to the front page and see this big text that says *14 day Free Trial* . So I have two questions

1. Do I need to create a seperate AppSee Account
2. Is AppSee free?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, not free
2. An email is generated.  If you check your email there is an email from AppSee so you can create your account

Answer (score 1):

From [Fabric](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/third-party-kits.html):

> Fabric has deprecated the third party kits as of August 2, 2018. As of
>   this date, you will not be able to onboard new third party kits via
>   Fabric to your apps
>
> Any existing apps using third party kits are not affected. Your
>   dashboard and how your app functions stay the same.

So,
1. You need to create an account in Appsee.
2. There is a version of Appsee that is free (for small teams), see [here](https://www.appsee.com/plans).

Comment: 14 Day Free Trail <> Free

Comment: I am not talking about a trial, there is a free version for small teams. I gave a link, you can see it there.